# Simplest Typescript + React + WebPack example generates errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When I compile a simple React/Typescript application (shown below), I get a variety of compiler warnings that do not appear to be from within my code.

```
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react-dom/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="main/ambient/react/index.d.ts" />

import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Example extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return <p> Hello! </p>;
  }
}

render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Although this example *does* run after compilation (via WebPack), it generates the following errors:

```
(19,22): error TS2339: Property 'createElement' does not exist on type '{}'.
(22,9): error TS2339: Property 'Component' does not exist on type '{}'.
(23,13): error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type '{}'.
(23,26): error TS2339: Property 'createElement' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I am running React v0.14.8. I am using these [typings for React](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/ecaf8c1c3f858e4b73f508c2a7dc831561d2097f/react/react.d.ts) and these [typings for React-dom](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711/react/react-dom.d.ts).[enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/56295f5058cac7ae458540423c50ac2dcf9fc711/react/react-dom.d.ts)

My question is: **Why does this example generate so many errors?** How can I resolve these errors?

Requested: tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react"
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Do you have a tsconfig.json file?

Comment: I have added the tsconfig.json for reference.

Comment: have you tried without the /// reference ? When using a tsconfig file you don't need those anymore. Also, you said it works with webpack, what version do you have of typescript installed globally? I'm assuming your getting the errors when running tsc

Comment: I was able to remove the compiler directives when used with webpack, but not with 'tsc'. tsc seems to work fine though, leading me to believe this might be an issue with webpack/ts-loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The bugs were caused by a plugin in WebPack (`new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()`). Removing this plugin solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) and define the types for your dependencies. You can also refer a very nice implementation of using `TypeScript` with `React` [here](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/working-with-react-and-typescript)

Comment: I mentioned that I am using typings at the bottom of the question (using the exact tool you mention). Are those not correct?